# Код на jQuery не работает

Tags: jquery

В html неправильный путь к картинке.Суть в том, чтобы поменять атрибут alt через 3 секунды после загрузки.Но таймер не работает куда бы я его не вставлял

```
$('img').ready(function(){
      $("img").delay(3000).attr('alt','Картинка загружена');
    });

`<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/96/ed/20/96ed206c3206f0cfb9a3abae7660873.jpg" alt="Картинка не загружена">`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В jQuery `.delay()` влияет только на анимацию или `.queue()`. Как вариант можно добавить смену атрибута внутрь `queue`.

```js
$('img').ready(function() {
  $("img").delay(3000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).attr('alt', 'Картинка загружена');
    next();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/96/ed/20/96ed206c3206f0cfb9a3abae7660873.jpg" alt="Картинка не загружена">
```

Comment: а ваще , если картинка загружена ...`alt` не видно же !

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, по идее да, но видимо по умолчанию стоит "картинка не загружена", а под каждую картинку свой текст, вроде бы похоже на разумное объяснение, сам делал что-то подобное

Comment: хм....интересно...какие только задачи бывают ...)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `setTimeout()` если хотите просто вызвать действие через определённое время:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('img').ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
   $("img").attr('alt', 'Картинка загружена');
  }, 3000)
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/96/ed/20/96ed206c3206f0cfb9a3abae7660873.jpg" alt="Картинка не загружена">
```